# preserve browser window focus when clicking on plugin

Tags: javascript, flash, window, onblur

I have a web page that uses javascript counters to count user "active" time, meaning the time a user spends viewing this page (and not some other page). I do this by starting/stopping them using the document.onfocusout/onfocusin (IE) and window.onblur/onfocus (other)
However, when the user clicks on a plugin inside the same page (flash, java, etc), the window loses focus and window.onblur is fired. Is there a way to tell that the user is still on my page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: edit: IE's counterparts, document.onfocusin and document.onfocusout don't seem to suffer from this issue, they retain the focus on the window

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem indeed. But you can trick your way out of it. Flash Player is able to communicate with its scripting host, in your case the JavaScript host. What you do is that when Flash Player movie receives focus, which I believe you are able to catch with ActionScript, you program it to notify it's host using the `ExternalInterface` Flash Player class API, which will say, call a JavaScript function, which will start the timer again (and optionally give focus back to the page because most often stealing focus from the page is a **bad idea**. Flash Player steals focus by default - if you click a Flash Player movie, keyboard is not caught by JavaScript any longer, only straight by Flash Player.)

Do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: I suppose you are implying to edit the flash code itself? This is not possible, as I am dealing with arbitrary content uploaded by users, which may also be inside an iframe. In addition, it doesn't address the java applet case.